# Changing WinForm Button Text Color?

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I'm wondering if it's possible to change the color of a WinForm Button's text.  I'm looking at the font properties, and can't find anything, but I feel like something as simple and (in my mind) practical as this should be possible ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need the `ForeColor` property of the button, inherited from `Control`.  See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.forecolor.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ForeColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.forecolor.aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the button `ForeColor` property

Answer (score 0):

```
Button btn = new Button();
//in this situation text color it will be black, for white 255,255,255
btn.Forecolor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0,0,0);
```

Comment: thanks for the alert, it's my first comment. is it ok this way?