# Dynamically change button font color c#

Tags: c#, button, fonts, colors

I want to change the font color of a button dynamically to red. How can i do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229690/changing-winform-button-text-color

Comment: couldn't thought of anything. I tried system.drawing

Comment: @RQDQ its a windows form application

Answer (score 7):

Is this what you're looking for?:

```
Button1.ForeColor = Color.Red; //System.Drawing namespace
```

Comment: ya exactly.thank you. but if i want to generalize this for every button, how can i do this??

Answer (score 2):

You need the `ForeColor` property of the button.

Comment: ya i've done this but if i want to generalize this for every button, how can i do this??

Comment: Define 'generelize'. You want it for all buttons on the form? Loop through the Form.Controls, check if it's a Button (Control is Button) and if it is, make ForeColor Red.

Comment: yes for all the buttons. Button.Forecolor is not valid and ((button)sender).forecolor is showing runtime error

Comment: Do something like; 

foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
{ if (c is Button) { ((Button)c).ForeColor = Color.Red; } }